# Using Powershell, I want to select an automatically opened .net web application as an object

Tags: .net, powershell, web-applications, automated-tests

So I'm in the early days of setting up some automated testing, and I'm using powershell ISE to open a url, then select a button.

```
$ie = New-Object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate("http://UrlAddress")
$ie.visible = $true
sleep 30
$Link=$ie.Document.getElementByID("LaunchBtn")
$Link.click()
```

This will automatically open a new .net application in a separate window. I now want the code to automatically select a button on this newly opened window.

Is there a way for me to create a new object using the new application window, without having to specify the url address?

If I try and simply link straight to the application's url, it recognizes that this is not a new session and won't let me access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Shell.Application COM object to enumerate [Internet] Explorer windows and check LocationURL:

```
$shellApp = New-Object -com Shell.Application
$ie2 = $shellApp.Windows() | ?{ $_.LocationURL -like "http://otheraddress*" }
```

Now `$ie2` contains IE document for that other address (or an array if many matching urls exist).